# Flattening an array in Flask API

Tags: python, api, post, flask

I'm making an API with flask that takes as a POST message body a nested array, and then returns a list of the values. An example would be curl …. –d ”(([[1, [], [2, 3]], [[4]], 5])” would return [1,2,3,4,5]. The flattening script works in the command line, but when I POST to the API, I get some weird results. Code is here:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar('PHIGITAL_SETTINGS', silent=True)


@lru_cache(maxsize=500)
def flatten(l):
    flattened = []
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, (list, tuple)):
            flattened.extend(flatten(el))
        else:
            flattened.append(el)
    return flattened

@app.route('/flatten', methods=['POST'])
def flatten_api():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            return jsonify({"response" : flatten(request.data)})
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({"response" : "ERROR: %s" % str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Testing this in Postman gets me the response: { "response": [ "[", "[", "1", ",", " ", "[", "]", ",", " ", "[", "2", ",", " ", "3", "]", "]", ",", " ", "[", "[", "4", "]", "]", ",", " ", "5", "]" ] }

Which is obviously not correct. I thought that it might have to do with the fact that request.data is a string, so I tried using ast.literal_eval to make request.data a list, but then I get the error "unhashable type: 'list'" when I try to call flatten on ast.literal_eval(request.data). I'm totally stumped and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, is it possible in Flask to return just a value, rather than a key value pair? I'd rather return just [1,2,3,4,5] rather than {"response": [1,2,3,4,5]}

Comment: Top-level arrays aren't supported by `jsonify` for security reasons. Just out of curiosity, why do you need an API endpoint for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use de-serialized data from Flask. Instead of `request.data` use `request.json`

Change your code to:

```
return jsonify({"response" : flatten(request.json)})
```

Comment: Then you most likely have forgot the `-H Content-Type:application/json` option to your curl command. Flask uses content-type to figure out how to handle input

Comment: I tested your code like this: `curl -d  '[1,222,[222,33321]]' -H Content-Type:application/json http://localhost:5000/flatten`